# Fedora 22 stuck in emergency mode

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I don't know for what reasons, but I'm stuck in emergency mode. I have never got this problem before. I'm reading about this and several places, i'm seeing that they are recommending to repair the partitions using `fsck`. However, I can barely see any partitions. `fdisk` isn't working and `/proc/partitions` is empty. Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

This is what I see before the above screen:

[image]

BIOS Info related to HD:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... not acquainted with fedora, but why not try to find logfiles to check; `dmesg | less` might be a start...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a problem with `fstab` pointing to a disk that no longer
exists (or that died).

The bad disk's signature is indicated in your screenshot.

I suggest to boot with a Live Linux disk and to examine the `fstab`.
You need to remove the bad entry in order to boot.

If the bad disk is your main disk, you have a problem.
You might also use the occasion of booting Live Linux to save any
irreplaceable data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have just added the boot options screen. If I understand, this information is from the hard disk, the boot partition. I have only one disk on my laptop. How can it say that the disk no longer exist but it still loads the boot partition from the disk

Comment: It seems to use a "rescue" boot image, meaning that it cannot access the main boot. There is a serious problem with your disk which might involve partial corruption. If you can use this rescue mode, or boot Live, examine the SMART info of the disk to find its status.

Comment: I used fedora live boot, i have used fdisk, disk utility and /dev/disk/by-id, i cannot find the drive in none of them, do you think it has already died?

Comment: Seems so. If Live Linux can't see it, I hope you have backups.

Comment: Weirdly, when I go to BIOS, and I try to add a boot option, i opens a pseudo file explorer when I see the HD physical device path, something like "PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17, 0x0)/Sata(0x400, 0x8000, 0x0)/HD" and when I click on it, i see entries like EFI, System and mac_kernel

Comment: Also, I added another image regarding HD, I can see it in the BIOS, also SMART reporting is enabled, and I do not get any erros regarding HD, i'm suspecting whether it can be related to BIOS update

Comment: You mean that the problem started after a BIOS update? You should definitely have said so, but for the moment return to the previous version.

Comment: No, I didn't know it was after a BIOS update but I suspected, and indeed it was, I tried downgrading and it's fine.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (✔). An upvote (△) would also be appreciated.